# Find out version of Redis running in PCF DEV

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

How to find out which version of Redis is running in [PCF DEV](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev)? I'm using the latest PCF DEV 1.2.0 for PAS 2.4.4 and created the service as per the docs, like this:

```
cf cs p.redis cache-small redis
```

It is running, and I have some app talking to it. Now I just want to know which version it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way with the help of a colleague: First, find out the hostname, port and password by querying the environment of the application which is successfully connected to Redis with `cf env [APP-NAME]`. The relevant chunk looks like this:

```
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
 "p.redis": [
  {
   "binding_name": null,
   "credentials": {
     "host": "q-s0.redis-instance.default.service-instance-deadbeef-8008.bosh",
     "password": "THXQCcElifUCCbJD2RlU7tgjZegmkn",
     "port": 6379
    },
(...)
```

Now, SSH into the apps container with `cf ssh [APP-NAME]` and use Netcat to connect to Redis:

```
vcap@...:~$ nc q-s0.redis-instance.default.service-instance-deadbeef-8008.bosh 6379
```

Then use `AUTH` and the password to "login"...

```
AUTH THXQCcElifUCCbJD2RlU7tgjZegmkn
+OK
```

...and issue the `INFO` command - the Redis version is displayed right at the top:

```
INFO
$3365
# Server
redis_version:5.0.2
(...)
```

Anyway, this is likely very much work for a tiny bit of information - are there other ways?